# Why are my "if statement" parameters not filtering my results properly?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I can clearly see in my results that one of the output results is "general". When I try to filter this out in my "if statement", it fails to catch the "general" everytime. My "str_replace" is an attempt to rid the results of any empty white space that might be causing the issue.

Code Snippet:

```
$tick = 0;
foreach($html->find('select.js-career-select') as $info) {

foreach($info->find('option') as $info2) {
    ++$tick;
    $general = 'general';

    if($tick > 38) {

        $list = $info2;
        $list = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $list));

        if($list != $general) {
            echo $list."<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo "NOPE!";
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($list)` on each iteration

Comment: Maybe there are newlines in `$list`.

Comment: Also: Only after 38 iterations will you start checking for 'general'.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Before 38 he doesn't print anything at all, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect `$list` has newlines before or after it. Try:

```
$list = strtolower(trim(strip_tags($list)));
```

to remove all types of whitespace surrounding the text, and any HTML tags in the text.

You can also get just the text from the tag with:

```
$list = $info2->plaintext;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still persists even with the trim

Comment: Try `echo htmlentities($list)` to see exactly what's in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally got it working after using $list = strip_tags($list);